# Como puedo seperar el dominio del hosting de un provedor y usar el hosting de otro proveedor?

Tags: hosting, dominio, godaddy

Actualmente tengo un proveedor que se contrato con un dominio y el hosting, pero como el hosting de site5 tiene almacenamiento limitado, optaron por comprar otro hosting el cual es godaddy. Lo que no entiendo y quiero saber si es posible, es saber  como puedo usar el dominio que tengo en site5, y que apunte al hosting que tengo en godaddy? tambien tengo otra pregunta se puede separar el dominio y el hosting del mismo provedor (site5)? Es la primera vez que trabajo con dominios y hosting de paga :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes tener el dominio y el hosting separados. Es incluso recomendable, sobre todo cuando hay que cambiar de hosting por algún motivo.

Para configurarlo necesitas dos sencillos pasos:

### Paso 1: En el hosting

Tienes que averiguar en el hosting (GoDaddy)  en tu caso, cuales son los **name servers**.

Suele aparecer en el apartado `Domains` de cPanel. O se lo puedes pedir al soporte técnico.

Puedes [revisar este enlace](https://es.godaddy.com/help/encontrar-mis-servidores-de-nombres-de-godaddy-12318), donde ellos indican los name servers, según lo que tengas contratado con ellos.

Esta imagen es de Bluehost, pero puede servir de orientación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Paso 2: en el registrador de dominios

Tienes que indicar que tu dominio apunta a GoDaddy, poniendo los **name servers**  obtenidos en el paso 1.

Debe haber una opción para poner nombres de servidores personalizados. Seguramente estarán allí los name servers propios del registrador. Debes borrar esos y poner los de GoDaddy.

Esta imagen es de mi registrador, pero igual te puede dar una idea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto a si se puede separar el dominio y el hosting del mismo proveedor no veo la posibilidad de hacerlo ni qué sentido tendría, a no ser que el proveedor tenga por una parte una empresa que administre el hosting y por otro lado otra empresa que administre los dominios. Aún así estarían separado...